# Is hajj outside of Dhul'Hijjah better than nothing?

Tags: practical-islam, hajj

As I know, around 2million people is on the Hajj every year.  There are around 1.5billion Muslims on the world. Half of them are male, which is 750million.  If they live 70 years long, then 140million Muslims can visit the Hajj.  Thus, around a fifth of Muslim men do the Hajj in their life.

However, the plane tickets are far cheaper outside of [Dhul'Hijjah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhu_al-Hijjah) (as far I know, particularly the planes coming back after transferring pilgrims are very cheap).

Thus, would doing the Hajj outside of Dhul'Hijjah be better than doing nothing, or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hajj(the greater Pilgrimage) can only be performed in the month of Dhul'Hijjah, specifically at the prescribed dates. A lesser pilgrimage, called [Umrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umrah), can be performed at any time of the year ... though its rites are slightly different, its virtue is lesser and it is **not** a *substitute* for Hajj.

Since the Umrah is not a substitute for Hajj, and the two are different rituals, the question of whether doing *Umrah* rather than not doing *Hajj* at all is similar to asking whether giving charity is better than not praying at all. Doing a good deed is better than doing nothing.

With that said, Hajj is only obligatory on those who are capable of doing it, both financially and due to health concerns etc. Not all 1.5 Billion Muslims are obliged to perform Hajj, not all of them are the same age, and the sacred Mosque's capacity is not fixed, but is expanded from time to time.

Comment: Thank you very much - very precise answer in the view, how is it better or not.